# Copy-Item copies folder inside the target when running second time

Tags: powershell, copy-item

During repetitive logs collection on my internal system, found strange behavior of recursive Copy-Item call

Say, i have C:\Source with some files and subfolders with files. I want to copy this recursively to C:\Target. For first time all source will be copied recursively to C:\Target

The problem happens when i try to copy "C:\Source" to "C:\Target" for second time.
In this case will "C:\Source" will be copied to "C:\Target\Source"

For example:

```
cls
if(Test-Path "C:\Target")
{
    Remove-Item "C:\Target"
}

Copy-Item "C:\Source" "C:\Target" -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
DIR "C:\Target" 
Write-Host "OK"
Write-Host " "
Write-Host " "

Copy-Item "C:\Source" "C:\Target" -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
DIR "C:\Target" 
Write-Host "Not OK"
```

Script output:

```
Directory: C:\Target


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                          
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                          
d----         4/11/2016   3:45 PM            SampleSourceFolderLevel1                                      
-a---         4/11/2016   3:35 PM          0 SampleFileLevel0.txt                                          
OK


d----         4/11/2016   3:45 PM            SampleSourceFolderLevel1                                      
d----         4/11/2016   3:45 PM            Source                                                        
-a---         4/11/2016   3:35 PM          0 SampleFileLevel0.txt                                          
Not OK
```

Any idea how can i make Copy-Item to work like

```
ROBOCOPY $sourceLog $targetLog /E | Out-Null
```

??

Thanks in advance

[Script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vO6Z.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want to copy the content of `c:\Source`. You just need to add `\*`:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\*" -Destination "C:\Target" -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
```

It works for the first run because you delete the target folder and the cmdlet now copies the folder `C:\Source` to `C:\Target`. If `C:\Target`exists, the cmdlet will copy the source **into** the Target folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, this copies only first level files items of **C:\Source**. If it has a sub-folder **C:\Source\Subfolder**, it will not be copied

Comment: Thanks, @jisaak. I see that this works for second time, but still does not work fine for first :). Do you know how to overcome this without creating target folder prior to copy item? [link] (http://i.imgur.com/BXgA75j.png)

Comment: The easiest solution would be to ensure the folder exists using `md 'C:\Target' -Force | out-null`

Comment: Thank you, @jisaak. That's the solution that i applied. Another option is to use robocopy. I just wanted to know if there any way to get consistent behavior from Copy-Item

Answer (score 0):

`Copy-Item` has inconsistent behaviour based on the fact if the destination exist or not.

If you want to have a consistent copy experience, use this pattern:

```
$copyFrom = 'C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy'
$destinationPath = 'D:\Bar\Foo\'

$newItemParams = @{
    Path        = $destinationPath
    ItemType    = 'Directory'
    Force       = $True
}

$copyParams = @{
    Path        = $copyFrom
    Destination = $destinationPath
    Recurse     = $True
    Confirm     = $false
    Force       = $True
}
New-Item @newItemParams
Copy-Item @copyParams
```

#### Result

The directory `D:\Bar\Foo\` will have `TargetDirectoryToCopy` directory nested inside.

So if there is a file `C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy\FooBar.txt`, its copy will be created as `D:\Bar\Foo\TargetDirectoryToCopy\FooBar.txt` along with any another file in `C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy`